# Did wheel bearing need to be removed in order to remove and add new stud?

Tags: wheel-bearing, wheel-hub

I previously asked question([What can cause a wheel to fall off/hub to break?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/57574/what-can-cause-a-wheel-to-fall-off-hub-to-break)) as my wheel hub stud snapped and answers said all that needed doing was putting new studs and nuts in.

Mechanic said ok however he came back later saying he couldn't simply remove and place the new stud because in order for the stud to be removed the wheel bearing had to first be removed and this increased the labour.

Here are diagrams for the front left wheel hub assembly (https://www.hondapartsnow.com/Page_Product/SearchByName.aspx?Vin=&Make=Honda&Model=Civic&Year=1999&Submodel=&Filter=(bt=1%2c11;et=2%2c3)&Keywords=WHEEL+HUB), please click image ref 3.

Based on the diagram I don't see any reason why the bearing would first have to be removed to remove and then place new studs, but I'm no mechanic.  Does the diagram suggest one might need to remove the bearing when replacing a broken stud or why might the mechanic have said that?

He also said ball joints needed to be cut but I'm not sure if its related to this issue but I thought I'll mention incase it is.

Thanks

Comment: I can't tell for sure on your Civic diagrams, nor have I done this work on your year of Civic personally, but *most* cars have a means by which you can use a punch to take the studs out, then use a lug nut (with washers if needed) and draw a new stud into place. If indeed the hub needed to come off, not sure why this wasn't mentioned when a quote for the work was given to you. By "means", I mean a hole or a slot where the stud can be taken in/out.

Comment: In my case of the nissan Titan ( front wheel of rear wheel drive) ; We drove the studs out with a punch with the hub in place .

Answer (score 2):

The hub has to be removed so that the old stud can be pushed out and the new one pressed in, but the bearing does not need to be removed from the hub itself. Perhaps the mechanic was talking about the "hub bearing unit or "hub bearing assembly"...

As for the ball joints being "cut"- I am not sure why the mechanic said "cut"- cracked is more relevant as the ball joints have to come apart - they work on a locking taper with a nut.

Comment: He specifically said he would need to pay someone to 'press' something in for him, he was either referring to the stud(since you say it needs to be pressed in) or he was referring to the bearing.  I guess he was referring to pressing in the stud then?